# XSLT: Nested for-each loop for Screenplay import

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

I made a xslt to import a xml in FileMaker.

The xml is a Screenplay I want to import and has this structure:

```
        <FinalDraft DocumentType="Script" Template="No" Version="3">
          <Content>
            <Paragraph Number="1" Type="Scene Heading">
              <SceneProperties Length="2/8" Page="1" Title="">
              </SceneProperties>
              <Text>Int. Containerhafen ContainerbrÜcke - tag </Text>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph Type="Action">
              <Text>Der Mann zündet sich eine Zigarette an und marschiert über das Terminal. Hafenarbeiter, die ihn passieren, grüßen respektvoll. Plötzlich klingelt sein Telefon. Der Mann bleibt stehen. Er zögert. Das Telefon klingelt weiter. Schließlich hebt er ab.</Text>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph Type="Character">
              <Text>Mann</Text>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph Type="Dialogue">
              <Text>Ja?</Text>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph Type="Action">
              <Text>Der Mann zündet sich eine Zigarette an und marschiert über das Terminal. Hafenarbeiter, die ihn passieren, grüßen respektvoll. Plötzlich klingelt sein Telefon. Der Mann bleibt stehen. Er zögert. Das Telefon klingelt weiter. Schließlich hebt er ab.</Text>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph Type="Character">
              <Text>Mann</Text>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph Type="Dialogue">
              <Text>Ja?</Text>
            </Paragraph>
        </Content>
        </FinalDraft>
```

The Paragraph "Scene Heading" with the Paragraph "Action, Character, Dialog" is repeating very often, for every scene in the screenplay.

I try do import a lot of informations in Filemaker, every Scene is one row: Scenenumber, Scene Length, Scene Heading Text, etc. And now I also want to import in one field every information of the scene at ones: "Scene Heading, Action, Character, Dialogue." The Scene Heading is no problem but "Action, Character, Dialogue" is repeating often, so I need a second "for-each" but I have Problem with the path and I don't no if this is the right way?

This is the XSLT, the problem part is on the very end on the last column "Szeneninhalt". I marked the path with "???" and it is a html code, because I need this in FileMaker.

```
 <RESULTSET>
        <xsl:for-each select="FinalDraft/Content/Paragraph[@Type='Scene Heading']">
        <ROW>
            <!-- Szenennummer
            -->
            <COL>
                <DATA>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Number"/></DATA>
            </COL>
            <!-- Szenenlaenge
            -->
             <COL>
                <DATA>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SceneProperties/@Length"/></DATA>
            </COL>
            <!-- Szenenbezeichnung
            -->
             <COL>
                <DATA><!--
                    <xsl:variable name="Szene" select="Text"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="replace('$Szene', 'Ext.', '123')" />
                    -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>

                 </DATA>

            </COL>
            <!-- Szenensynopsis
            -->
         <COL>
                <DATA>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Paragraph[@Type='Action']/Text"/></DATA>
            </COL>
             <!-- Drehbuchname
            -->
         <COL>
                <DATA>
                    Drehbuch Ersatzname
                    </DATA>
            </COL>
                  <!-- ExtInt
            -->
         <COL>
                <DATA>
                <xsl:if test="contains(Text, 'Ext.')">
                    <p>Ext.</p>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="contains(Text, 'Int.')">
                        <p>Int.</p>
                    </xsl:if>
                    </DATA>
            </COL>
                             <!-- TagNacht
            -->
         <COL>
                <DATA>
                <xsl:if test="contains(Text, 'tag')">
                    <p>Tag</p>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="contains(Text, 'nacht')">
                        <p>Nacht</p>
                    </xsl:if>
                    </DATA>
            </COL>
            <!-- Szeneninhalt
            -->
         <COL>
                <DATA>
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
                    &lt;ul class="screenbox"&gt;
                    &lt;li class="scenenumber"&gt;<xsl:value-of select="@Number"/>&lt;/li&gt;
                    &lt;li class="sceneheader"&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Text"/>&lt;/li&gt;

                    <xsl:for-each select=" ??? ">

                    &lt;li class="action"&gt;<xsl:value-of select=" ??? "/>&lt;/li&gt;
<!--
                        &lt;li class="character"&gt;<xsl:value-of select=" ??? "/>&lt;/li&gt;
                    &lt;li class="dialogue"&gt;<xsl:value-of select=" ??? "/>&lt;/li&gt;
-->                    
                    </xsl:for-each>       
                    &lt;/ul&gt;       
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
             </DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW></xsl:for-each>

    </RESULTSET>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: 1. I am not sure it's a good idea to put all the paragraphs of a scene in the same field. I would suggest you use separate records in a related table. -- 2. I could not understand the format you want to use if and when putting them in a single field. I think it would be (another) mistake to mix data with formatting.  Keep your data clean and if you need to display it as HTML, use a separate process.

Comment: I want to show every scene page in FileMaker like a real screenplay page, I can to this with a "web viewer" it's a field where I render html code. My idea was to prepare the html code in the xslt, in Filemaker is it not so easy to do this. But I'm also not sure if this is the right way. The separation of the paragraphs in the xml is more for a better formatting and not for data. the xml its the way of the screenplay app.

Comment: I am quite sure it is NOT the right way. Just think what would it take if you wanted to change the HTML code even slightly. The correct way is to have the HTML code as a template in the web viewer or in a script that populates the web viewer. This template would use the **data** in your records/fields to produce the HTML on demand. It's not that difficult to do (and you can always ask another question about it).

Comment: Yes, if I think about it now, it might make more sense to first import the data cleanly into FileMaker and distribute it in FileMaker and process it the way I need it. On the one hand, I need an overview of all scenes with the information because they are processed further then the "Webviewer" view of the scene itself. I'll try this way, thanks for the food for thought! - One more question that does not quite fit this topic, but maybe you have an idea or link to a post: How do I get the file name of the xml in FileMaker?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 does not know the file name. If you need it, use a Filemaker script to get it (for example, insert the XML into a container field first, then export it to temp and import it from there).